# Github Actions to run Jupyter notebook scripts

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, cron, github-actions, jupyter

I have an environment set up in jupyterhub with all my production scripts. Firstly I was using Jupyter_Scheduler to run my jobs however it's very inconsistent and requires server reboots time to time. I had a look into Github Actions which looks promising and I've got my workflow yaml file set up but if my jupyter notebook scripts contain credential checks which is stored in the OS within jupyterhub, will Github Actions be able to access this? I'm unsure of how it will communicate with each other.

my end goal is:

- Set up a cron schedule using github actions
- run my jupyter notebook scripts that is currently on my jupyterhub which i will be cloning to my github repo.
- Safe method of accessing credentials within my script, which at the moment i am storing in my OS

Thanks!

Comment: Check out the GitHub Actions documentation, particularly about secrets [here](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/using-secrets-in-github-actions). I also found some duplicate posts in my search e.g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68978306/how-to-reference-github-secrets-in-github-actions-workflow-for-renviron-file) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59481933/how-can-i-extract-secrets-using-github-actions) that might help you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For GitHub Actions there is something called [secrets](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/using-secrets-in-github-actions), which I strongly suggest you use if you don't want anybody else to see your tokens/passwords.
As to how you get them onto the repository: if your secrets don't change you can just set them manually, but if they do change regularly you can take a look at the [API for setting secrets](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/actions/secrets?apiVersion=2022-11-28#create-or-update-a-repository-secret) and write a script that automatically creates/updates the secrets

Comment: okay this worked thank you!